# Extrude in FME for lines

Tags: fme-form, 3d, extrude

I tried to extrude walls in FME from chopped lines (2 vertices). I am using ground height to extrude.  The middle portion of the lines for the building slope roof is not extruding correctly.

[image]

Comment: I'm unclear why you have this tagged with `arcgis-10.0` because you do not mention that software in your question.  If it is not relevant to it can you edit your tags to remove it, please?

Comment: is there any method in Arcgis for roof lines extrude

Comment: Please provide more info. What data was your original file in? Which fme function did you use.

Comment: Convert your lines to Polygons (GeometryCoercer) http://fmepedia.safe.com/articles/Samples_and_Demos/3D-Building-Generator-Workspace

Comment: FME Extrude transformer I used.

Comment: I think we'd need to see the source data to know what's going on. If you can submit it to the FME support team they can check it out. http://safe.com/supportrequest

Comment: any suggestions ?..

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you create a buffer with a negative value using the thickness of the wall as a reference, then you extrude the polygons resulting from the buffering.